JetBrains Rider could not copy Azure.Function.Worker
When using JetBrains Rider to debug an Azure Function every other re-build/build I get the following error message:

Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(169,9): Warning MSB3026 : Could not copy "C:*\Local\Temp\2n3kt121.jsm\buildout\bin\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.FunctionMetadataLoader.dll" to "C:\Dev**\bin\Debug\


Then I have to look for a process 'func' and close it manually or close and re-open Rider to make it build again. This is very frustrating. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Delete the folder C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools folder and run the function again.


Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets(169,9): Warning MSB3026 : Could not copy "C:Local\Temp\2n3kt121.jsm\buildout\bin\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.FunctionMetadataLoader.dll" to "C:\Dev\bin\Debug\

To resolve this error, delete the Azure Function Tools folder under C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\ (as mentioned in the comments)=> restart the Rider IDE and run the function.


Navigate to the project root directory=> delete the  bin  and  obj  folders and rebuild the project, this forces Rider to clean and rebuild the entire project from scratch and resolves configuration issues if there is any.
Clear cache in Rider, navigate to  File=>Invalidate Caches=>Invalidate Restart.



According to the screenshot provided in the question, the function seems to be isolated azure function.
Install all the required packages for your project.

Isolated function:
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.16.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.11.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.7.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="8.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

launchsettings.json:
{  
  "profiles": {  
  "FunctionApp1": {  
  "commandName": "Project",  
  "commandLineArgs": "--port 7147",  
  "launchBrowser": false  
      }  
    }
 }

